# TikZ: how to use inner and outer linewidth at a shape (or path)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I found in the TikZ-Handbook, page 1022 lines which have 3 parts in different colors and widths: one inner linewidth and two outer lines. 
But this has a `pgfpicture`-code...

I asked myself: *How can I use that at a shape?* 
I would like to have an **inner line (pink, 5mm)** and **two outer lines above and below (black, very thin)**. Is that possible?

Hint: **I do not want to draw three separate shapes** (the brute force solution is clear).

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
TikZ-Manual, p. 1122:

\begin{pgfpicture}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}
\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}
\pgfsetinnerlinewidth{1pt}
\pgfsetinnerstrokecolor{red!50}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfpicture}

How to use here?

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[rounded rectangle, draw, pink,
minimum width=50mm, minimum height=20mm, line width=5mm,
](s){*};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply a `preaction` with a thicker line or a `postaction` with a thinner line:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[rounded rectangle, draw=pink, line width=5mm,
minimum width=50mm, minimum height=20mm, preaction={draw=red, line width=6mm},
](s){*};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 6):

If you are fine with the inner and the outer line having the same style, you can use a `double` line:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[
    rounded rectangle, 
    minimum width=50mm, 
    minimum height=20mm, 
    draw=black, 
    line width=0.5mm, 
    double=pink,
    double distance=5mm
] (s) {*};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice too. ;)

Answer (score 4):

The first three examples (after the one from the manual) show how to do exactly the same as the PGFpicture with TikZ. TikZ doesn't provide a direct interface to `\pgfsetinnerlinewidth` but also adjusts the *outer* (see below) line width when one of `double distance` or `double distance between line centers` is used. Though, I've added a direct interface to `\pgfsetinnerlinewidth` which needs the user to adjust `line width` on their own.

When you use `double` (or `\pgfsetinnerlinewidth`) PGF/TikZ draws a path twice, first with an “*outer*” line width/color and then with the *inner* line width/color.

This means the *inner* line width needs to be smaller than the *outer* line width for `double` to have a visual effect (unless opacity comes into play).

This is probably also the reason why TikZ makes sure that the PGF line width (which becomes the *outer* line width) is adjusted so that
with `double distance` and `double distance between line centers`
the line width (as given by the user) is added to the *inner* line width

- on “both sides” of the *inner* line width with `double distance` and
- so that it overpaints the given width with `double distance between line centers` (I hope my last TikZpicture is clearer than my words).

---

Since you want

> […] to have an **inner line (pink, 5mm)** and **two outer lines above and below (black, very thin)**.

you need

```
double distance = 5mm
```

and

```
line width = <very thin>
```

and PGF/TikZ will draw the black line with `line width = 5mm + 2 × <very thin>` but overpainting a strip of `5mm` directly afterwards leaving black stripes of `<very thin>`.

I've used `ultra thin` (0.1pt) but of course you can adjust it.

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{inner line width/.code=%
  \tikzset{double}\pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{#1}%
  \edef\tikz@double@setup{\noexpand\pgfsetinnerlinewidth{\the\pgf@x}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}
\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}
\pgfsetinnerlinewidth{1pt}
\pgfsetinnerstrokecolor{red!50}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikz
  \draw[
    line width = .5pt,     % \pgfsetlinewidth{.5pt}
    double distance = 1pt, % \pgfsetinnerlinewidth{1pt}
                       % and \pgfsetlinewidth     {1pt + 2 * \pgflinewidth}
    double=red!50          % \pgfsetinnerstrokecolor{red!50}
  ]   (0pt, 0pt)           % \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
   -- (1cm, 1cm)           % \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}
   -- (1cm, 0cm)           % \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}
   ;                       % \pgfusepath{stroke}
\tikz
  \draw[
    line width = .5pt,     % \pgfsetlinewidth{.5pt}
    double distance between line centers = 1.5pt,
                           % \pgfsetinnerlinewidth{\pgflinewidth - 1.5pt}
                       % and \pgfsetlinewidth     {\pgflinewidth + 1.5pt}
    double = red!50        % \pgfsetinnerstrokecolor{red!50}
  ] (0pt, 0pt) -- (1cm, 1cm) -- (1cm, 0cm);

\tikz
  \draw[line width=2pt, inner line width=1pt, double=red!50]
    (0pt, 0pt) -- (1cm, 1cm) -- (1cm, 0cm);

\tikz
  \node[rounded rectangle, draw, double=pink, double distance=5mm, ultra thin,
       minimum width=50mm, minimum height=20mm](s){*};
       
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=5mm] (-.25,-.25) grid (3.25,2.8);

\tikzset{double=red, nodes={white, align=center, scale=.4}}\ttfamily
\draw[double distance=5mm,                      line width=2mm]  (0,0.25) -- node{dd = 5mm,    lw = 2mm\\→ ilw = 5mm, olw = 5 + 2×2mm} + (right:3);
\draw[double distance between line centers=5mm, line width=2mm]  (0,1.25) -- node{ddblc = 5mm, lw = 2mm\\→ ilw = 5mm - 2mm, olw = 5mm + 2mm} + (right:3);
\draw[inner line width=5mm,                     line width=10mm] (0,2.25) -- node{ilw = 5mm,   lw = 10mm\\→ ilw = 5mm, olw = 10mm}     + (right:3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]